# In file './docker-compose.yml', service 'image' must be a mapping not a string

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml

I want to create a *.yml file* that i can execute to use wordpress with mysql. I'm new about docker, docker compsoe so my code is:

```
web:
    image: wordpress
    links:
     - mysql
    environment:
     - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=sample
    ports:
     - "127.0.0.3:8080:80"
mysql:
image: mysql:latest
environment:
 - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=sample
 - MYSQL_DATABASE=wordpress
```

I do `docker-compose up` and i obtain this error:

```
ERROR: In file './docker-compose.yml', service 'image' must be a mapping not a string.
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: fix the `image: mysql:latest` indentation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a yaml formatting error.
You should format it like this

```
web:
    image: wordpress
    links:
     - mysql
    environment:
     - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=sample
    ports:
     - "127.0.0.3:8080:80"
mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    environment:
     - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=sample
     - MYSQL_DATABASE=wordpress
```

Answer (score 1):

indentation is wrong near `mysql:` Please correct the indentation as below

```
web:
image: wordpress
links:
 - mysql
environment:
 - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=sample
ports:
 - "127.0.0.3:8080:80"
mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=sample
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=wordpress
```

You may validate the yml here https://onlineyamltools.com/validate-yaml